# Writing a simple function using while

Tags: python

A Python HOMEWORK Assignment asks me to write a function “that takes as input a positive whole number, and prints out a multiplication, table showing all the whole number multiplications up to and including the input number.”(Also using the while loop)

```
 # This is an example of the output of the function
print_multiplication_table(3)
>>> 1 * 1 = 1
>>> 1 * 2 = 2
>>> 1 * 3 = 3
>>> 2 * 1 = 2
>>> 2 * 2 = 4
>>> 2 * 3 = 6
>>> 3 * 1 = 3
>>> 3 * 2 = 6
>>> 3 * 3 = 9
```

I know how to start, but don’t know what to do next. I just need some help with the algorithm. **Please DO NOT WRITE THE CORRECT CODE**, because I want to learn. Instead tell me the logic and reasoning. 
*Here is my reasoning:*

1. The function should multiply all real numbers to the given value(n) times 1 less than n or (n-1)
2. The function should multiply all real numbers to n(including n) times two less than n or (n-2)
3. The function should multiply all real numbers to n(including n) times three less than n or (n-3) and so on... until we reach n
4. When the function reaches n, the function should also multiply all real numbers to n(including n) times n
5. The function should then stop or in the while loop "break"
6. Then the function has to print the results

So this is what I have so far:

```
def print_multiplication_table(n): # n for a number
    if n >=0:
        while somehting:
            # The code rest of the code that I need help on

    else:
        return "The input is not a positive whole number.Try anohter input!"
```

**Edit:** Here's what I have after all the wonderful answers from everyone

```
"""
i * j = answer
i is counting from 1 to n
for each i, j is counting from 1 to n 
"""


def print_multiplication_table(n): # n for a number
    if n >=0:
        i = 0
        j = 0 
        while i <n:
            i = i + 1
            while j <i:
                j = j + 1
            answer = i * j
            print i, " * ",j,"=",answer

    else:
        return "The input is not a positive whole number.Try another input!"
```

It's still not completely done! 
For example:

```
print_multiplication_table(2)
# The output 
>>>1  *  1 = 1
>>>2  *  2 = 4
```

**And NOT**

```
>>> 1 * 1 = 1
>>> 1 * 2 = 2
>>> 2 * 1 = 2
>>> 2 * 2 = 4
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of using a while condition that will loop forever, you should consider a while condition that ends when your multiplications achieve "up to and including the input number".

Comment: I can only use while loops.

Comment: Hint: One way of solving this is to use nested `for` loops. If you don't know about these, please [**read the Python tutorial**](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements).

Comment: RE: Robert Harvey,
The while loop should not loop forever, it should stop at some point. Maybe I should change the while loop statement.

Comment: @frsfnrrg: His homework assignment requires that he only use `while` loop(s).

Comment: Write a version with `for` and convert the loops into `while`s then.

Comment: There are an uncountably infinite number of real numbers up to any given value. Did you mean integers, or something different?

Comment: Answering questions this basic without just giving you the code is tricky.  The best thing to do would be to talk to your instructor (or drop into the tutoring center if you have one) and have them work with you to understand the material..

Comment: As a hint to follow up on timrau's: Any loop `for i in range(a, b): do_stuff(i)` can be rewritten as shown [in this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/wxhc0rSb).

Comment: +1 I must say this is a refreshing post. You, sir or madam, are the antithesis of a help vampire. Just for your future learning, I would note that in real life where you're not limited to `while` loops, it would be more Pythonic to use something like `range` with some mix of generators, `product` from `itertools`, and/or `map` or similar. It would result in shorter, more readable code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a little mad about the `while` loop requirement, because `for` loops are better suited for this in Python. But learning is learning!

Let's think. Why do a `While True`? That will never terminate without a break statement, which I think is kind of lame. How about another condition?

What about variables? I think you might need two. One for each number you want to multiply. And make sure you add to them in the `while` loop.

I'm happy to add to this answer if you need more help.

Your logic is pretty good. But here's a summary of mine:

stop the loop when the product of the 2 numbers is `n * n`.

In the mean time, print each number and their product. If the first number isn't n, increment it. Once that's n, start incrementing the second one. (This could be done with if statements, but nested loops would be better.) If they're both n, the `while` block will break because the condition will be met.

As per your comment, here's a little piece of hint-y psuedocode:

```
while something:
    while something else:
        do something fun
        j += 1
    i += 1
```

where should original assignment of i and j go? What is something, something else, and something fun?

Comment: Thank you very much for this wonderful answer. I understand it more. However I still need your help, so just give me some time, while I try to write a function of the way you described to me.

Comment: @Andy, good luck! Fair warning: I described this function in a totally non-pythonic way (that will work). When this isn't for an assignment, use nested `for` loops!

Comment: FWIW, I think the pedagogical point here is to demonstrate that you can implement something semantically equivalent to a `for` loop with a `while` loop and that, therefore, `for` is really no more than syntactic sugar. It goes toward recognising iteration as an abstraction and a fundamental concept. I think it's a pretty good exercise for a beginning programming class.

Comment: @Emmet That's a very good point, and I absolutely agree. I was assuming the teacher was being lazy and didn't want to think up a good example for a `while` loop, but I see now that you're right.

Comment: @ rogaos,
This is what I tried, but it has some problems:
http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user17_autAKO7jvR7bdqd.py

Comment: @Andy those inner `while` loops are running all the way through without doing any multiplication. You'll only need an one inner loop and an outer loop, and you should have all of your logic within the inner loop. Try to write it without break statements! You're going to want to increment one variable inside one loop, and the other outside. See my edit in a minute.

Comment: @rogaos I can't see the edit, click on "Save" and share the url with me.

Comment: @Andy I meant the edit to my answer. I commented on your codeskulptor a little just now. http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user17_autAKO7jvR7bdqd_1.py

Comment: @Andy: nice try, but I think you're over-complicating it. Think about your table. What's happening in the first column? And the second? Does that suggest any “containment” relationship (one thing inside another thing) at all? Like, maybe, loops going from 1 to 3?

Comment: @Andy gotta go. Listen to Emmet, he's more rational than I am.

Comment: @Emmet Here's the new code. What's wrong with j?
http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user17_ertcwyBnZc1u2iK_0.py

Comment: @Andy: very close! Watch your indentation: what statements are under the control of what iteration constructs? Also, consider what values (i/j) you're initializing and where. I did a (pretty minor) rearrangement of your code that works perfectly.

Comment: @Emmet Can you be more specific?And what should I initialize (i/j)? None? 1?  I am totally confused!

Comment: Maybe this will help. Ask yourself this: what is `j` when your innermost `while` loop ends and when it starts again? Emmet already pointed out you have an indentation error. Look over your code and ask yourself, "Which `while` loop does this part belong in?"

Comment: Whoops. Forgot the @Andy

Comment: @jpmc26 Thanks for standing by. Right now I am just writing code and trying different things to get the right answer. So far so good! But it's getting late night ;(

Comment: @Andy: did you get any further after I was whisked away yesterday?

Comment: @Emmet Yeah, a lot further. I wrote the whole thing. Now I am just debugging it.I have the code, but the problem now is with indentation, which I am trying to figure out.Here's where I am: http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user17_ertcwyBnZc1u2iK_2.py
And thanks for remembering me!I really appreciate all of your help.

Comment: @Andy: nearly there! So the outer (`i`) loop should run `n` times, and the inner (`j`) loop should run `n` times for every `i` (or `n`*`n` times in total). So, just one thing: what will the initial value of `j` be the _second_ time the inner (`j`) loop runs? Should `j` be set to its starting value (`j=0`) in the same place as `i`, as you have it, or somewhere else?

Comment: @Emmet, Yes I got it.Here: http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user17_ertcwyBnZc1u2iK_3.py
But why should (j=0) be placed in the (i loop)?

Comment: @Andy well done. You should look at your code line by line and look at what the variables are at every point. That should give you a much better understanding of why everything is where it is. Just one more thing - your function returns the error message, and prints out everything else. Depending on how you're planning to execute the function, you might want to change `return` to `print`. If you do that, Python will automatically return `none`.

Comment: @Andy, because otherwise, the `j`-loop will only run the first time the `i`-loop runs. The second time through the `i`-loop, the value of `j` already meets the termination criterion (j>=n) for the `j`-loop, and the `j`-loop is completely skipped. This is because `j`'s value hasn't changed since the last time through the `i`-loop because you haven't reset `j` in the `i`-loop as you should (and now have).

Comment: @Emmet,Oh, that's why. Well that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @Andy: it always makes perfect sense after you understand it :)

Comment: Now everything is done.I wrote the code, and it does what I wants it to, and I understand how everything works in the code. Thank you Emmet,rogaos,jpmc26,arshajii,and everyone else who contributed to this post.I learned, and I got what I wanted.I really appreciate all of your affords, and helpful insights. Thank you all very much!! :)

Answer (score 2):

This problem is better implemented using nested loops since you have two counters. First figure out the limits (start, end values) for the two counters. Initialize your counters to lower limits at the beginning of the function, and test the upper limits in the while loops.

Answer (score 2):

The first step towards being able to produce a certain output is to recognize the pattern in that output.

```
1 * 1 = 1
1 * 2 = 2
1 * 3 = 3
2 * 1 = 2
2 * 2 = 4
2 * 3 = 6
3 * 1 = 3
3 * 2 = 6
3 * 3 = 9
```

The number on the right of `=` should be trivial to determine, since we can calculate it by multiplying the other two numbers on each row; obtaining *those* is the core of the assignment. Think of the two operands of `*` as two counters, let's call them `i` and `j`. We can see that `i` is counting from `1` to `3`, but *for each* `i`, `j` is counting from `1` to `3` (resulting in a total of 9 rows; more generally there will be n<sup>2</sup> rows). Therefore, you might try using nested loops, one to loop `i` (from `1` to `n`) and another to loop `j` (from `1` to `n`) for each `i`. On each iteration of the nested loop, you can print the string containing `i`, `j` and `i*j` in the desired format.